# Updating property wrapper like @StateObject, affects other view rendering that does not use that property

Tags: swift, swiftui, view, dependencies, rendering

When using different property wrappers associated with view updates, changes in one place affect rendering of views that do not use that property.

[image]

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @StateObject var viewModel = MyViewModel()
    @State var thirdTitle = "thirdTitle"

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(viewModel.firstTitle)
                .background(.random)
            Text(viewModel.secondTitle)
                .background(.random)
            Text(thirdTitle)
                .background(.random)

            Button("Change First Title") {
                viewModel.chageFirstTitle()
            }
        }
    }
}

class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var firstTitle = "firstTitle"
    @Published var secondTitle = "secondTitle"
    
    func chageFirstTitle() {
        firstTitle = "hello world"
    }
}
```

I understand that the reason why the `Text` exposing the `viewModel.secondTitle` is re-rendered is because the `@StateObject varviewModel = MyViewModel()` dependency changed when the `viewModel.firstTitle changed.

However, I don't know why `Text` using `@State var thirdTitle = "thirdTitle"` is re-rendered too. In WWDC21 session [Demystify SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/?time=390), I saw that the view is re-rendered only when the related dependency is updated according to the dependency graph. But, even though the `thirdTitle` is irrelevant to the change of the `viewModel`, third `Text` using that dependency is re-rendered and the background color is changed.

What's even more confusing is that if I seperate the third `Text` into a separate view ( `ThirdView` )  and receive the `thirdTitle` using `@Binding`, the background color does not change because it is not re-rendering at that time.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @StateObject var viewModel = MyViewModel()
    @State var thirdTitle = "thirdTitle"

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(viewModel.firstTitle)
                .background(.random)
            Text(viewModel.secondTitle)
                .background(.random)
            ThirdView(text: $thirdTitle)
                .background(.random)

            Button("Change First Title") {
                viewModel.chageFirstTitle()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ThirdView: View {
    
    @Binding var text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .background(.random)
    }
}
```

[image]

Regarding the situation I explained, could you help me to understand the rendering conditions of the view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To render SwiftUI calls `body` property of a view (it is computable, i.e. executes completely on call). This call is performed whenever any view dependency, i.e. dynamic property, is changed.

So, `viewModel.chageFirstTitle()` changes dependency for `ContentView` and `ContentView.body` is called and every primitive in it is rendered. `ThirdView` also created but as far as its dependency is not changed, its `body` is not called, so content is not re-rendered.

Answer (score 1):

A few things wrong here. We don't use view model objects in SwiftUI for view data, it's quite inefficient/buggy to do so. Instead, use a struct with mutating funcs with an `@State`. Pass in params to sub-Views as lets for read access, `@Binding` is only when you need write access. In terms of rendering, first of all `body` is only called if the let property is different from the last time the sub-View is init, then it diffs the body from the last time it was called, if there are any differences then SwiftUI adds/removes/updates actual UIKit UIViews on your behalf, then actual rendering of those UIViews, e.g. `drawRect`, is done by CoreGraphics.

```
struct ContentViewConfig {
    
    var firstTitle = "firstTitle"
    var secondTitle = "secondTitle"
    
    mutating func changeFirstTitle() {
        firstTitle = "hello world"
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var config = Config()
    ...

struct ThirdView: View {
    let text: String
    ...
```

Combine's `ObservableObject` is usually only used when needing to use Combine, e.g. using `combineLatest` with multiple publishers or for a `Store` object to hold the model struct arrays in `@Published` properties that are not tied to a View's lifetime like `@State`. Your use case doesn't look like a valid use of `ObservableObject`.