# View disappears when using Toggle()-button in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a problem in the following code, that whenever I use the Toggle()-Button the SettingsEx1View disappears and the Exercise1View() appears. They are connected with the ObservableObject Profile(). I get [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56980875/what-does-invalid-mode-kcfrunloopcommonmodes-mean) error when starting the app, but it seems that is a bug with SwiftUI Apple has to fix. The weird thing is, that when I delete line 18 and 19

```
    let osc = DynamicOscillator()
    let audioEngine = AudioEngine()
```

it works perfectly fine. Is there something I have overlooked or do you know anything I could do? Any help is appreciated, thanks!!

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation
import AudioKit
import SoundpipeAudioKit
import Foundation

class Profile: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var playSoundeffects = true
    @Published var waveformIndex = 0

}

struct Exercise1View: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var profile: Profile
        
    let osc = DynamicOscillator()
    let audioEngine = AudioEngine()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(
            destination: SettingsEx1View())
        {
            Image(systemName: "gearshape.circle")
        }
            .navigationTitle("Exercise1")
    }
}

struct SettingsEx1View: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var profile: Profile
    let waveformOptions = ["sine", "triangle", "sawtooth", "square"]
    
    var body: some View {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("General")) {
                    Toggle("play soundeffects", isOn: $profile.playSoundeffects)
                    Picker("waveform", selection: $profile.waveformIndex) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< waveformOptions.count) {
                            Text(self.waveformOptions[$0])
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Settings")
    }
}

struct HomeScreen: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var profile: Profile
    @AppStorage("playSoundeffects") var playSoundeffectsSave: Bool = true
    @AppStorage("waveform") var waveformIndexSave: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
                NavigationLink(destination: Exercise1View())
                {Text("Exercise1")}
        }
        .onAppear {
            profile.playSoundeffects = playSoundeffectsSave
            profile.waveformIndex = waveformIndexSave
        }
        .onChange(of: profile.playSoundeffects) { newValue in
            playSoundeffectsSave = profile.playSoundeffects
        }
        .onChange(of: profile.waveformIndex) { newValue in
            waveformIndexSave = profile.waveformIndex
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HomeScreen()
            .environmentObject(Profile())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HomeScreen.body` depends on `Profile` settings, so when latter updated it is refreshed and `NavigationView` is **recreated** as part of `body`, so its navigation stack destroyed.

As `NavigationView` does not depend on `Profile` itself a simplest solution is to separate it into stand-alone view, like

```
struct HomeScreen: View {
    
    // ... other code
    
    var body: some View {
      MainView()
        .onAppear {
            profile.playSoundeffects = playSoundeffectsSave

    // ... other code
}

struct MainView: View {
  var body: some View {
        NavigationView{       // << here !!
                NavigationLink(destination: Exercise1View())
                {Text("Exercise1")}
        }
  }
}
```

See also this for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72824345/12299030